Generator With Adjustable Resistance
I'm currently working on a project that uses a DC brushed motor (24V, 350W) as a generator. I want to be able to adjust the resistance of the generator. The device will be battery powered, so ideally I would be able to use the generator to charge the battery.
Right now, my plan is two-fold: use PWM with a power resistor at low voltages, and then use a DC-DC converter to charge the battery at higher voltages.
Low voltage: PWM with power resistor

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The plan is for 1 ohm resistance, run at 100% duty cycle, for n ohm resistance (n > 1), run at (1/n)*100% duty cycle.
Questions about this:

Is C1 required? Since driving motors with PWM doesn't usually require a capacitor, is that the same for a generator configuration?
If R1 is rated at 100W, would 200W at 50% duty cycle be ok, given a high PWM frequency?
Will running at a (1/n)*100% duty cycle actually result in an apparent n ohm resistance?

High voltage: Motor -> DC-DC Converter -> LiPo
When the voltage is large enough to work with a DC-DC converter, I am planning to connect the generator to a DC-DC converter and adjust the voltage output of the converter to control the power into the battery. By measuring current and voltage on the generator side, I should be able to adjust the voltage so I get a desired "resistance."
Question about this:

What limits the charging current of a LiPo? I know the general consensus is to charge at 1C, but would charging at 2 or 5C for short periods of time (10 seconds) be dangerous if the temperature is monitored and is at an acceptable level?
Should a capacitor be placed across the motor terminals to smooth the voltage into the DC-DC converter?


What do you mean "adjust the resistance of the generator"?

@Hearth I mean making it easier/harder to turn. I'm assuming that mechanical resistance is inversely proportional to electrical resistance.

maybe adjustable torque would be a better phrase

As you say, when you PWM a brushed DC permanent magnet motor, usually the motor has enough inductance so that you can dispense with any further filtering components and just use the switch. You can pull the same trick when  using the motor as a generator, without wasting precious human input power in a power resistor.
In your case, you can use the generator's inductance as part of the boost converter to the batteries, and use PWM to control the torque required to turn the generator.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The conceptually simplest way to do this is to have an inner loop controlling the PWM to draw a programmed average current from the generator.
Controlling the current drawn from the generator controls the torque (or mechanical resistance) required to turn it, directly.
Then you have a simple outer loop that controls the mean current drawn, to perform battery charge current/voltage limiting, constant torque or power to the generator, etc.
The inner loop operates like this. Close the PWM switch across the generator to short-circuit it. Monitor the current, and as it builds, open the switch when it has reached your target current plus a hysteresis amount. The voltage spike from the motor's inductance is your boost DC output, take this via a diode to your batteries. The generator output current will now be falling quickly, under the influence of the large output voltage. Close the PWM switch when the current has fallen below your target current by your hysteresis amount. The cycle repeats.
If you simply control the generator current, then as you turn the generator faster, the torque will stay the same, so the mechanical power will increase, and you will charge the battery faster (the PWM duty cycle will alter to maintain the generator average current). An alternative control algorithm is to control the power, and there you will reduce your generator target current as the speed increases, or as the battery mean charging current increases.
You will also want to limit the battery max charge current, and max voltage on charge. for safety. You implement either of these by simply reducing the generator target current into your PWM controller. Note that when the battery is charged, the inner loop would now be set to pull no current from the generator.
If this is part of an exercise machine, you will need a dump resistor as an alternative load, to absorb the excess power. You can use the same inner loop current control to control the amount of power it absorbs, and so load imposed by the generator.
You may find that measuring the very noisy current of a brushed PM generator is impractical for controlling the PWM cycle by cycle. It may be better to control the duty cycle of the PWM directly, adjusting the duty cycle with respect to a filtered measurement of the current.
Bear in mind that, like any boost converter, if the supply voltage exceeds the output voltage, control will be lost as the load will be driven straight from the diode. If it's likely that the generator will be turned so fast that it exceeds the battery charge voltage, then you either need to disconnect the battery, or load the generator to stop the user turning it.

Should I add a capacitor in parallel with the battery to reduce the ripple voltage?

@jb0 If it makes you feel better, then there's no harm, but it would need to be huge to do anything significant. It's one of those unnecessary and insufficient things, being shorted by the battery low impedance. An LC filter OTOH would do something, but it's still not required. Note that the current is well controlled by the generator's inductance and the PWM control algorithm, so the battery is having a low, slowly-changing, current thrown at it. That's pretty tame, and it will set its own terminal voltage in response to the current.
